# postgresql: additional WHERE-clause hides rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

My SQL-request joins 2 tables, result are payment amounts, grouped by payment method. Payment methods are present in `payment_history` table: *BlueMedia*, *Transferuj, BankPayment* and *ChangeSum*. Also `payment_history.payment_method` column can contain empty string or `NULL` - in that case I want to retrieve it as 'other' value.

SQL-query is:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(payment_history.payment_method, '') = '' THEN 'other'
        ELSE payment_history.payment_method
    END as payment_method, 
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(paid_balance) IS NULL THEN 0.00
        ELSE SUM(paid_balance)
    END as paid_balance, 
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(sum_without_commission) IS NULL THEN 0.00
        ELSE SUM(sum_without_commission)
    END as sum_without_commission                   
FROM 
    payment_history 
    LEFT JOIN 
    participants_list ON payment_history.registration_id = participants_list.registration_id 
WHERE 
    payment_history.client_id = 258 AND
    participants_list.deleted = 0 AND
    participants_list.is_reserved = 0
GROUP BY payment_history.payment_method
```

Result (no records with payment method *Transferuj*, it's OK, cause it's absent for current client with `id`= 258):

[image]

`other` means, that records are present in `payment_history`, where `payment_method` is `NULL` or empty string.

I **don't want** to retrieve records, where payment method is `ChangeSum`. So, I've added appropriate condition in query:

```
...
WHERE payment_history.client_id = 258 
AND payment_history.payment_method != 'ChangeSum'
...
```

But in result set also `other` is empty:

[image]

Why does it occur and what can I do to get data with needed methods (including `other`, when `payment_method` column contains `NULL`||empty string; but **without** `ChangeStatus`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what jarlh has expalined about `left join` and `where` clauses, you can simplify your query with `coalesce()` and you can use `coalesce()` around a nullable value for comparisons so they do not return `null`.

```
select 
    coalesce(payment_history.payment_method, 'other') as payment_method
  , coalesce(sum(paid_balance),0.00) as paid_balance
  , coalesce(sum(sum_without_commission),0.00) as sum_without_commission
from payment_history 
  left join participants_list 
    on payment_history.registration_id = participants_list.registration_id 
   and participants_list.deleted = 0 
   and participants_list.is_reserved = 0
where payment_history.client_id = 258 
  and coalesce(payment_history.payment_method,'')!='ChangeSum'
group by payment_history.payment_method
```

When comparing `payment_method` is null, `null != 'ChangeSum'` will return `null`, not true. [Comparison Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html)

To expand on the `null` comparison issue:

`Null` is treated as `unknown`, so comparison to `null` is always `unknown`,  so if you filter on `null != 'ChangeSum'` the result is not `true` (it is `null`), and your `where` only includes results where your conditions are `true`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html

Using `coalesce(payment_history.payment_method,'')!='ChangeSum'` returns `true` when `payment_method` is `null`, because `coalesce` is substituting the `null` value with `''` for the comparison and `'' != 'ChangeSum'` is `true`.

Comment: Thank u, it works! I will post my answer (I need to use `NULLIF` too, cause it can be empty string also, not only `NULL`), but exactly your answer will be accepted.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I'm not a profi in SQL. Could u, please, explain, why `coalesce(payment_history.payment_method,'')!='ChangeSum'` allows me to see `other`? I understood, that problem is in case, when `payment_method` contains `NULL`, but didn't understand, how it prevents retrieving row `other`... Namely, what's going on with result when `payment_method` contains `NULL` and `null != 'ChangeSum'` returns `null`?..

Comment: @Boolean_Type `null` is treated as `unknown`, so comparison to `null` is always `unknown`,  so if you filter on `null != ' ChangeSum'` the result is not `true`, it is `null`, and your `where` only includes results where your conditions are `true`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: @Boolean_Type using `coalesce(payment_history.payment_method,'')!='ChangeSum'` returns true when `payment_method` is `null`, because `coalesce` is substituting the `null` value with `''` for the comparison and `'' != 'ChangeSum'`

Answer (score 2):

When `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table conditions in the `ON` clause. (When in `WHERE`, you'll get regular `INNER JOIN` result.)

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(payment_history.payment_method, '') = '' THEN 'other'
        ELSE payment_history.payment_method
    END as payment_method, 
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(paid_balance) IS NULL THEN 0.00
        ELSE SUM(paid_balance)
    END as paid_balance, 
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(sum_without_commission) IS NULL THEN 0.00
        ELSE SUM(sum_without_commission)
    END as sum_without_commission                   
FROM payment_history 
LEFT JOIN participants_list 
ON payment_history.registration_id = participants_list.registration_id 
  AND participants_list.deleted = 0 
  AND participants_list.is_reserved = 0
WHERE payment_history.client_id = 258 
GROUP BY payment_history.payment_method
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it can't be helpful for me: **1)** you are right, I need exactly `INNER JOIN` result, so I can't put the right side table conditions in the `ON` clause (but I will write `INNER` instead of `LEFT`); **2)** it doesn't answer my question: how to get `other` row, when I add condition `AND payment_history.payment_method != 'ChangeSum'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`is distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html):

```
and payment_history.payment_method is distinct from 'ChangeSum'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SqlZim and @jarlh I've changed my query. There is valid variant below:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(NULLIF(payment_history.payment_method, ''), 'other') AS payment_method, 
COALESCE(SUM(paid_balance), 0.00) AS paid_balance,
COALESCE(SUM(sum_without_commission), 0.00) AS sum_without_commission                  
FROM payment_history 
INNER JOIN participants_list 
ON payment_history.registration_id = participants_list.registration_id 
WHERE payment_history.client_id = 258 
AND participants_list.deleted = 0 
AND participants_list.is_reserved = 0
AND COALESCE(payment_history.payment_method, '') != 'ChangeSum'
GROUP BY payment_history.payment_method
```

Also it's possible to write

`AND payment_history.payment_method IS DISTINCT FROM 'ChangeSum'`

instead of

`AND COALESCE(payment_history.payment_method, '') != 'ChangeSum'`

, as @Clodoaldo Neto proposed.